# Excel VBA loop keeps randomly skipping lines

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Macro that is designed to take information in the format it's given to us and copy it to the format we need. For the most part this works great - however, there are consistent problems with the same line types where it creates the comment but does not copy the value over, making it seem like there's no data even when there it. When I step through it, even on the skipped lines, it works fine - but when I activate the entire macro, it still skips.

I looked at other threads to try to figure out what might be causing it and tried a couple of possible solutions, such as marking the entire sub as Option Explicit and making it manually recalculate before copying, but it's still skipping lines.

This is the loop

```
' r is range, p is position, t is counter, c is count of lines

 For t = 0 To c
            On Error Resume Next
           ' for now, skips ones without row numbers
            p = (5 + t)
            Pickup = "A" & CStr(p) ' cell reference for row number
            r = ActiveSheet.Range(Pickup)
            Address = "J" & CStr(p) ' total to be pasted
            Dropoff = "Y" & CStr(r) ' paste address on cost validation tab
            Comment = "I" & CStr(p) ' address of comment on data paster tab
            Range(Address).Calculate
            Range(Address).Copy
                Worksheets("Cost Validation").Range(Dropoff).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                ' Range(Address).Value2 = Worksheets("Cost Validation").Range(Dropoff).Value2
                Worksheets("Cost Validation").Range(Dropoff).AddComment Range(Comment).Value
                
        Next t ' loops through til end of active cells count
```

Comment: You should remove the `On Error Resume Next` statement and check if you have any runtime errors

Comment: Damn. That does actually seem to have stopped it skipping - I had it there to skip over the rows of data that we didn't need. I'll try putting those in a cell and clearing that cell between loops and seeing if that work without the On Error.